# Cannot find module 'glob'

Tags: npm, angular, angular-cli

**Tell me what extra information you need**

Im following a simple guide to activate my first angular 2 app and did the following actions on the clr:

```
npm i -g angular-cli    //(worked)

ng new ponyracer        //(error: Cannot find module 'glob')
ng serve                //(error: Cannot find module 'glob')

Cannot find module 'glob'
Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stavalfi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\addon\ng2\tasks\lib-install.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Any explations about the commands "ng new ponyracer" and "ng serve" will be great.

Thanks,
Stav

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's already an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/233) reporting this error message. The workaround until the next release is to install `glob` for the project (`npm install --save glob`)

Regarding the commands, according to their repository under [Generating and serving an Angular2 project via a development server](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server) the commands are as follow

`ng new ponyracer` : This command will create a project named `ponyracer` (a folder named *ponyracer* with all the set up in it).

`ng serve` : This command will run the [live reload server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) to serve the application so you can see it in your browser.

PS : If you test the solution suggested in the issue it would be nice of you to report if it worked or not.

PS2 : I tested now (I fixed my error) and I cannot reproduce your error. I'm using node v5.5.0 and npm v3.7.3. Can you specify which node and npm versions are you using?

Comment: Did that and now I get new error after doing : "ng serve" : "You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.". What does he want? :(

Comment: Enter to the directory ponyracer and run ng serve

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on Windows 10,

```html
D:\Code\AngularJS>ng new greetings-ac
Cannot find module 'glob'
Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\node_modules\angular-cli\addon\ng2\tasks\lib-install.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

but the following fixed it:

D:\Code\AngularJS>npm install -g angcli

```html
D:\Code\AngularJS>ng new greetings-ac
? Select project blueprint: Default template
Cloning into 'D:\Code\AngularJS\greetings-ac'...
install installing using npm
npm WARN package.json angularApp@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json angularApp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angularApp@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.7
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@3.10.2: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.7
```

Answer (score 2):

For now, run `npm install --save glob` in your project, or install globally `npm install -g glob` like Eric mentioned.

This is listed in [Issue #233](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/233) on the angluar-cli project.

> The missing glob dep has been fixed in latest master. This will go out
>   in the next release. - posted 4/21/16

Versions ran with this fix:

- angular-cli: 0.0.33
- node: 5.9.1
- glob: 7.0.3
- angular2: 2.0.0-beta.14

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Cannot find module 'module_name'

Error: Cannot find module 'module_name'

When I run the command:

> npm install --save module_name

Note: Here the 'module_name' is the name of the missing module. example: fs-extra, glob, dependency-graph, sort-package-json, @phosphor/coreutils, prettier etc.

It throws a new error that a new module is missing. And it kept happening everytime I try to fix an error, a new error pops up the next time(other packages mentioned above).

Here's what I did to solve the error:

I had to uninstall and unlink nodejs and npm :
Note: use unlink only if you have linked them before, otherwise, it's not necessary

> brew uninstall node
>
> brew unlink node
>
> brew unlink npm
>
> brew unlink node_modules

Make sure you remove all the node_modules, npm and nodejs folders from your system.
My commands below can be different from yours. You can manually search for folders and remove them as well:

> rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
>
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp

After uninstalling and deleting all node, npm folders, I ran these commands:

> brew install node
>
> npm install yarn -g
>
> npm install -g typescript
>
> npm install
>
> yarn install

That fixed all the issues

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer is pretty specific to MacOs, and the asker appears to be using Windows (per the `C:\` file paths in the error message). Might want to saying this answer worked for MacOs in your answer, and be a little more agnostic when answering and point to more specific documentation elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove node_modules
2. remove package-lock.json
3. npm i
4. npm run ...