# Nuxt fatal error "cannot find module 'dir-glob'"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I had a Nuxt app running. I restarted the server (note: it ran fine the first time) with `npm run dev` and now I get the above error. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525436/cannot-find-module-glob) but it's 5 years old and about Angular. The full terminal output is:

```
FATAL  Cannot find module 'dir-glob'
13:40:16
Require stack:
- C:\web\learn\cosmico\node_modules\globby\index.js

  Require stack:
  - node_modules\globby\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:94:19)
  at m (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:52953)
  at f (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:53766)
  at node_modules\globby\index.js:6:17
  at f (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:54655)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\components\dist\index.js:9:16
  at Resolver.f [as _require] (node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:54655)
  at Resolver.requireModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:381:29)
  at ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:182:38)


   ╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                         │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                    │
   │                                                         │
   │   Error: Cannot find module 'dir-glob'                  │
   │   Require stack:                                        │
   │   - C:\web\learn\cosmico\node_modules\globby\index.js   │
   │                                                         │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cosmico@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cosmico@1.0.0 dev script.
```

This started happening after I installed Nuxt's [postcss8 module](https://github.com/nuxt/postcss8).

[ EDIT ]

My nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'cosmico',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Comment: You installed this one and followed what's been told here? What is the content of your `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: Added. It's basically what `nuxt-generate-app` generated for me.

Comment: Nah I just kept running into errors so in the end I just restarted the whole project and elected to use Yarn instead (someone said somewhere they find they get fewer errors with Yarn). Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: I do use yarn too, faster and subjectively better haha.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the usage section of the [nuxt/postcss8 documentation](https://github.com/nuxt/postcss8#usage), it says that you need to do the following:

- `npm install @nuxt/postcss8 --save-dev`
- add the following to your `nuxt.config` file

```js
export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/postcss8'
  ]
}
```

---

### Update regarding the current bounty

The issue is related to an old project.
Javascript frontend realms tends to move quickly and node versions, package managers and lock files may require some maintenance over time.

The resolution of some packages can be faulty sometimes too (regarding dependency graphs, unavailable or retired/renamed projects on NPM etc...), hence why some project may not be able to build anymore.

Nuking the `node_modules` and running a `npm i` may fix things, otherwise using a [frozen lock file](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4147#issuecomment-321792657) could also be useful. But it also mainly depends of some breaking changes regarding a possible package you're using.
Some of them require that you ditch some kind of cache, especially if the change is at a low level of a Webpack/SASS/etc...dependency engine.

For further details and an efficient debugging session, we would need your personal configuration to try to narrow down where this may come from.

PS: `yarn` and `PNPM` are usually also better at providing readable errors. On top of not having some weird issues with non-installed dependencies (especially if using PNPM's `shamefully-hoist=true` and `auto-install-peers=true` flags into your `.npmrc` project's file).

Comment: Doing step 1 of that (I did the NPM version rather than Yarn) brings up more errors: `npm ERR! Object for dependency "setprototypeof" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".` I run `npm install` to regenerate the package file, as it says, and it results in the same errors again.

Comment: Delete your `package-lock.json` file, clean the cache with `npm cache clean` and run `npm i` again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. How do you know this stuff? When you met these errors first time, how on earth did you know what to do? It's hardly intuitive...

Comment: Haha, it's die-and-retry, a lot of googling and praying a lot in front of your computer yeah!

Comment: @salim added more details to my answer.

Comment: @kissu thank you! I'm sorry I missed the date to award the bounty

Comment: @SalimMahboubi damn unfortunate I guess.